# Getting wrong answer in codechef : A Balanced Contest

Tags: c++

The link to the problem is "https://www.codechef.com/OCT17/problems/PERFCONT"
I have worked out a solution to this problem but I am getting wrong answer.

My solution:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
long long int hard,cakewalk,t,temp;
long long int n,p;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
    hard = cakewalk = 0;
    cin>>n;
    cin>>p;
    while(n--){
        cin>>temp;
        if(temp<=(p/10))
            hard++;
        if(temp>=(p/2))
            cakewalk++;
        if(hard>2 || cakewalk>1){
            break;
        }
    }
    if(hard==2 && cakewalk ==1){
        cout<<"yes"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"no"<<endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

As I have gathered we have to calculate the number of Hard and Cakewalk type problems and if there exactly 2 and 1 respectively, it's a balanced contest. 
Kindly help me in solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting WA because you are breaking when `hard > 2 || cakewalk > 1` without reading the whole input line. So, after it breaks and gives the correct input for the given test case, but it will fail because the number that is next inputted is technically not the input for the next test case. It is the remaining part of first test case.

For input:

```
2
4 100
1 1 1 1
2 100
1 50
```

For the first test case, you skip taking input after reading 1 1 1 from line 3. So, the next input you take is 1 (considering it to be n) whereas n should be 2 for next test case.

Removing this should work:

```
 if(hard>2 || cakewalk>1){
            break;
  }
```